# How can I post data to django import_export

Tags: django, testing, django-admin, django-import-export, django-unittest

I would like to test the import function from import_export django. When I run my test the code says I provide **no dataset (None)** even though I do provide a proper CSV file. Thus, my assertions (starting from `self.assertIn('result', response.context)`) fail.

Why don't my resource class and `def import_data` see the dataset I provide in `response = self.client.post(import_url, data=data)`?

My test:

```
class ImportUserCase(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.admin = User.objects.create(login='admin', email='admin@example.com', password='password', is_staff=True, is_superuser=True)
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.force_login(self.admin)
        self.resource = UserImportResource()
    
    def test_import_action(self) -> None:
        import_url = '/admin/core/user/import/'
        process_url = '/admin/core/user/process_import/'
        
        input_format = '0'
        filename = 'users.csv'
        with open('users.csv', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(UserImportResource.Meta.fields)
            writer.writerow('test', 'test@gmail.com', 'test, 'test', 'test)
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            data = {
                'input_format': input_format,
                'import_file': f,
            }
            response = self.client.post(import_url, data=data)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

            self.assertIn('result', response.context) 
            self.assertFalse(response.context['result'].has_errors())
            self.assertIn('confirm_form', response.context)
            confirm_form = response.context['confirm_form']

            data = confirm_form.initial
            self.assertEqual(data['original_file_name'], 'books.csv')
            response = self.client.post(process_url, data,follow=True)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

My resource:

```
class UserImportResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        instance_loader_class = UserLoader
        fields = ('login', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender')
        use_transactions = False

    def get_import_id_fields(self):
        return ['email']

    def get_import_fields(self):
        return [self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_field_names()]

    def get_import_field_names(self):
        return ('login', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender')

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        to_delete = []
        for idx, row in enumerate(dataset.dict):
            if not row['email'] or not row['email'].strip():
                to_delete.append(idx)
        for idx in sorted(to_delete, reverse=True):
            del dataset[idx]

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        if not row['email']:
            return
        row['email'] = row['email'].strip()

    def import_data(self, dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False,
                    use_transactions=None, collect_failed_rows=False, **kwargs):
        print(f'dataset: {dataset}') # says None instead of the real dataset
        result = self.get_result_class()()
        fns = self.get_import_field_names()

            if header not in fns or header == 'id':
                err_msg = 'Error'
                result.append_base_error(self.get_error_result_class()(err_msg))
                return result

        user_logins_search = {str(row['login']).strip() for row in dataset.dict}
        available_login_map = {}
        for user_data in User.objects.filter(login__in=user_logins_search).values('login', 'email'):
            available_login_map[user_data['login']] = user_data['email']

        using_transactions = False if dry_run else True
        with atomic_if_using_transaction(using_transactions):
            return self.import_data_inner(dataset, dry_run, raise_errors, False, collect_failed_rows, **kwargs)

    def get_user_visible_fields(self):
        return self.get_import_fields()
```

Comment: Best thing to do would be to use a debugger and step through the process starting at [`import_action()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/ebf58e0fe6b27285bb1c9bdfcfff0792bd7ad116/import_export/admin.py#L502).  You could use existing tests in the repo for comparison.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty, thank you for your reply. I had a look at import_action() and I must tell you that ```data = tmp_storage.read(input_format.get_read_mode())``` is empty. Even though ```tmp_storage = self.write_to_tmp_storage(import_file, input_format)``` seems to work properly and save my csv. 

Any ideas?

Comment: obviously read is failing for some reason.  In the absence of any errors, I suggest review [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#importing), and update your question if you can find more information.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty, thank you very much for your help. The problem was that in the admin class ```tmp_storage_class``` was set to ```import_export.tmp_storages.CacheStorage```. Apparently, when you run django unittests ```CacheStorage``` does not keep its data, that's why even though there was a proper CSV file ```tmp_storage.read(input_format.get_read_mode())``` could not read anything and supplied the further code with an empty dataset.

As soon as I replaced ```CacheStorage``` with ```FileSystemStorage``` the test ran successfully.